# suspend in ubuntu 12.04 doesn't work correctly

Tags: 12.04, suspend, vaio

After click the "suspend" in ubuntu 12.04 laptop screen turns black, but does not turn off. Notebook cooler continues to work, the LEDs on the connected USB flash drives are still lit. What to do? (Notebook sony vaio vgn-cr31sr).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not "turned off"? From personal experience, when putting my laptop into suspend under 12.04 the laptop goes into a low power state (power light flashes) as it should. It still provides some power to the USB ports however, the laptop cooling stand still works and the mouse light is still on for example.

So if this is the case for you, then I guess all is working as it should. If you don't like power going to USB during suspend, someone has asked this question before: [Suspend USB power to a laptop cooling pad when going to suspend mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99474/suspend-usb-power-to-a-laptop-cooling-pad-when-going-to-suspend-mode)

If your laptop is not going into a proper suspend (laptop internal fan is still on, power light is on and not flashing, hard drive whirring, keyboard LEDs on or other signs of life) then it might be worth mentioning these in your question. Also say if you can wake it from this state by pressing the power button.